# How to push OpenCV Images into GStreamer Pipeline to stream it over the TCPServer-Sink

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I'm trying to push Images created by OpenCV into the GStreamer-Pipeline in order to stream a video through the GStreamer-TCPServerSink.

My GStreamer-Pipeline looks as follows: **AppSrc -> FFMpegColorSpace -> VP8Enc -> WebMMux -> TCPServerSink**
The AppSrc is feed by creating OpenCV-Images and push them into Appsrc via **gst_app_src_push_buffer**.

I've written a little Testprogram called "Sandbox", that shows the Error that occurs in GStreamer, when the Program runs.

My Testsystem looks as follows:

- Gentoo
- Kernel: 3.10.0-rc3
- OpenCV: 2.4.5
- GStreamer: 0.10.36

#### I want to understand why this Error occurs, what i'm doing wrong and how a working Solution might look like?

I hope, that you can help me to solve the Problem.

I've set up a Mini-CMake Project containing the code the produces the Error. It consists of two Files, namely CMakeLists.txt and Sandbox.cpp. CMakeLists.txt is Configuration on howto build the Sandbox Program contained in Sandbox.cpp.
To build it just create a Directory e.g. "Build", change into it and start an Out-of-Source Build with:

```
cmake ../
```

Now CMake creates all needed files, if you have the Dependencies installed, so you can just type:

```
make
```

to build the Program.

```
####################################################################################################
# Projectinformations
####################################################################################################
project( Sandbox CXX )
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8 )

####################################################################################################
# G++ Options
####################################################################################################
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc" )
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++" )

set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -O0 -std=c++11 -ggdb -Wall -W -Wunused-variable -Wunused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused -Woverloaded-virtual -Wwrite-strings --coverage" )
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} )

####################################################################################################
# Resolve Dependencies
####################################################################################################
set( Boost_DEBUG 1 )
set( Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED 1 )
find_package( Boost 1.53 REQUIRED system thread timer )

find_package( PkgConfig )
pkg_check_modules( GSTREAMER_0_10 gstreamer-0.10 )
pkg_check_modules( GSTREAMER_0_10_APP gstreamer-app-0.10 )
include_directories( ${GSTREAMER_0_10_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
include_directories( ${GSTREAMER_0_10_APP_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

####################################################################################################
# Project
####################################################################################################
add_executable( Sandbox Sandbox.cpp )
```

The Program itself looks as follows:

```
// Standard C++ Libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

// Boost Libraries
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

// GStreamer
#include <gstreamer-0.10/gst/gst.h>
#include <gstreamer-0.10/gst/gstelement.h>
#include <gstreamer-0.10/gst/gstpipeline.h>
#include <gstreamer-0.10/gst/gstutils.h>
#include <gstreamer-0.10/gst/app/gstappsrc.h>

// OpenCV
// #include "cv.h"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>


GMainLoop *glib_MainLoop;
unsigned int heartbeat_Intervall; ///< In Milliseconds
boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::deadline_timer> heartbeat;

GstElement *source_OpenCV;
guint64 imagecounter;

void
GLib_MainLoop() {
    if( !g_main_loop_is_running( glib_MainLoop ) ) {
        std::cout << "Starting glib_MainLoop..." << std::endl;
        g_main_loop_run( glib_MainLoop );
        std::cout << "Starting glib_MainLoop stopped." << std::endl;
    }
};

/// Creates an Image with a red filled Circle and the current Time displayed in it.
cv::Mat
Create_Image() {
    cv::Size size = cv::Size( 640, 480 );
    cv::Mat image = cv::Mat::zeros( size, CV_8UC3 );
    cv::Point center = cv::Point( size.width / 2, size.height / 2 );
    int thickness = -1;
    int lineType = 8;

    cv::circle( image, center, size.width / 4.0, cv::Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ), thickness, lineType );

    std::stringstream current_Time;
    boost::posix_time::time_facet *facet = new boost::posix_time::time_facet( "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S.%f" );
    current_Time.imbue( std::locale( current_Time.getloc(), facet ) );
    current_Time << boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();

    int font = cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX;
    double fontsize = 1;
    int font_Thickness = 1;

    int baseline = 0;
    cv::Size textSize_01 = cv::getTextSize( current_Time.str(), font, fontsize, font_Thickness , &baseline );
    baseline += font_Thickness;

    cv::Point textOrg_01( ( image.cols - textSize_01.width ) / 2, ( image.rows + textSize_01.height * 2 ) / 2 );
    cv::Scalar textcolour = cv::Scalar( 0, 255, 0 );
    cv::putText( image, current_Time.str(), textOrg_01, font, fontsize, textcolour , font_Thickness , 1 );

    return image;
}

/// Creates a Graph of the created Pipeline including the contained Elements. The environment variable "GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR" must be set, e.g to /tmp/ to actually create the Graph.
/// Furthermore GST_DEBUG needs to be activated, e.g. with "GST_DEBUG=3".
/// So "GST_DEBUG=3 GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR=/tmp/" ./Sandbox would work.
/// The .dot file can be converted to a e.g. svg-Graphic with the following command (Package GraphViz): dot -Tsvg -oPipelineGraph.svg PipelineGraph.dot
void
Create_PipelineGraph( GstElement *pipeline ) {
    bool debug_active = gst_debug_is_active();
    gst_debug_set_active( 1 );
    GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE( GST_BIN( pipeline ), GST_DEBUG_GRAPH_SHOW_ALL, "PipelineGraph" );
    gst_debug_set_active( debug_active );
}

void
Push_new_Image( const boost::system::error_code &error ) {
    if( error != 0 ) {
        std::cout << "Error in Timer: " << error.message() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    cv::Mat image = Create_Image();

    /// OpenCV handles image in BGR, so to get RGB, Channels R and B needs to be swapped.
    cv::cvtColor( image, image, CV_CVTIMG_SWAP_RB );

    {
        /// How do i get the actual bpp and depth out of the cv::Mat?
        GstCaps *caps = gst_caps_new_simple( "video/x-raw-rgb", "width", G_TYPE_INT, image.cols, "height", G_TYPE_INT, image.rows, "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 0, 1, NULL );
        g_object_set( G_OBJECT( source_OpenCV ), "caps", caps, NULL );
        gst_caps_unref( caps );

        IplImage* img = new IplImage( image );
        uchar *IMG_data = ( uchar* ) img->imageData;

        GstBuffer *buffer;
        {
            int bufferlength = image.cols * image.rows * image.channels();
            buffer = gst_buffer_new_and_alloc( bufferlength );

            /// Copy Data from OpenCV to GStreamer
            memcpy( GST_BUFFER_DATA( buffer ), IMG_data, GST_BUFFER_SIZE( buffer ) );

            GST_BUFFER_DURATION( buffer ) = gst_util_uint64_scale( bufferlength, GST_SECOND, 1 );
        }

        /// Setting the Metadata for the image to be pushed.
        {
            GstCaps *caps_Source = NULL;

            std::stringstream video_caps_text;
            video_caps_text << "video/x-raw-rgb,width=(int)" << image.cols << ",height=(int)" << image.rows << ",framerate=(fraction)0/1";
            caps_Source = gst_caps_from_string( video_caps_text.str().c_str() );

            if( !GST_IS_CAPS( caps_Source ) ) {
                std::cout << "Error creating Caps for OpenCV-Source, exiting...";
                exit( 1 );
            }

            gst_app_src_set_caps( GST_APP_SRC( source_OpenCV ), caps_Source );
            gst_buffer_set_caps( buffer, caps_Source );
            gst_caps_unref( caps_Source );
        }

        /// Setting a continues timestamp
        GST_BUFFER_TIMESTAMP( buffer ) = gst_util_uint64_scale( imagecounter * 20, GST_MSECOND, 1 );
        imagecounter += 1;

        /// Push Buffer into GStreamer-Pipeline
        GstFlowReturn rw;
        rw = gst_app_src_push_buffer( GST_APP_SRC( source_OpenCV ), buffer );

        if( rw != GST_FLOW_OK ) {
            std::cout << "Error push buffer to GStreamer-Pipeline, exiting...";

            exit( 1 );
        } else {
            std::cout << "GST_FLOW_OK " << "imagecounter: " << imagecounter << std::endl;
        }

    }

    /// Renew the Heartbeat-Timer
    heartbeat->expires_from_now( boost::posix_time::milliseconds( heartbeat_Intervall ) );
    heartbeat->async_wait( Push_new_Image );
}

int
main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    std::cout << "Sandbox started." << std::endl;

    /// ####################
    /// Initialise Sandbox
    /// ####################
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> io_service = boost::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service>();
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work = boost::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service::work>( *io_service );
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread_group> threadgroup = boost::make_shared<boost::thread_group>();

    /// io_service Callback for continuously feeding into the pipeline of GStreamer.
    /// I've using to push the Buffer into GStreamer as i come available instead of getting informed about an empty pipeline by GStreamer-Signals.
    heartbeat_Intervall = 1000; ///< In Milliseconds
    heartbeat = boost::make_shared<boost::asio::deadline_timer>( ( *( io_service.get() ) ) );

    std::cout << "Initialise GStreamer..." << std::endl;
    gst_init( &argc, &argv );

    glib_MainLoop = g_main_loop_new( NULL, 0 );

    std::cout << "Start GLib_MainLoop..." << std::endl;
    io_service->post( GLib_MainLoop );

    /// Create some Workerthreads
    for( std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i )  {
        threadgroup->create_thread( boost::bind( &boost::asio::io_service::run, &( *io_service ) ) );
    }

    /// ####################
    /// Do the actual Work
    /// ####################
    GstElement *pipeline;
    GstElement *converter_FFMpegColorSpace;
    GstElement *converter_VP8_Encoder;
    GstElement *muxer_WebM;
    GstElement *sink_TCPServer;


    /// Create GStreamer Elements

    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new( "OpenCV_to_TCPServer" );

    if( !pipeline ) {
        std::cout << "Error creating Pipeline, exiting...";
        return 1;
    }

    {
        source_OpenCV = gst_element_factory_make( "appsrc", "Source_OpenCV" );

        if( !source_OpenCV ) {
            std::cout << "Error creating OpenCV-Source, exiting...";
            return 1;
        }

        gst_bin_add( GST_BIN( pipeline ), source_OpenCV );
    }

    {
        converter_FFMpegColorSpace = gst_element_factory_make( "ffmpegcolorspace", "Converter_FFMpegColorSpace" );

        if( !converter_FFMpegColorSpace ) {
            std::cout << "Error creating Converter_FFMpegColorSpace, exiting...";
            return 1;
        }

        gst_bin_add( GST_BIN( pipeline ), converter_FFMpegColorSpace );
    }

    {
        converter_VP8_Encoder = gst_element_factory_make( "vp8enc", "Converter_VP8_Encoder" );

        if( !converter_VP8_Encoder ) {
            std::cout << "Error creating Converter_VP8_Encoder, exiting...";
            return 1;
        }

        gst_bin_add( GST_BIN( pipeline ), converter_VP8_Encoder );
    }

    {
        muxer_WebM = gst_element_factory_make( "webmmux", "Muxer_WebM" );

        if( !muxer_WebM ) {
            std::cout << "Error creating Muxer_WebM, exiting...";
            return 1;
        }

        gst_bin_add( GST_BIN( pipeline ), muxer_WebM );
    }

    {
        sink_TCPServer = gst_element_factory_make( "tcpserversink", "Sink_TCPServer" );

        if( !sink_TCPServer ) {
            std::cout << "Error creating Sink_TCPServer, exiting...";
            return 1;
        }

        gst_bin_add( GST_BIN( pipeline ), sink_TCPServer );
    }


    /// Link GStreamer Elements

    if( !gst_element_link( source_OpenCV, converter_FFMpegColorSpace ) ) {
        std::cout << "Error linking creating source_OpenCV to converter_FFMpegColorSpace, exiting...";
        return 2;
    }

    if( !gst_element_link( converter_FFMpegColorSpace, converter_VP8_Encoder ) ) {
        std::cout << "Error linking creating converter_FFMpegColorSpace to converter_VP8_Encoder, exiting...";
        return 2;
    }

    if( !gst_element_link( converter_VP8_Encoder, muxer_WebM ) ) {
        std::cout << "Error linking creating converter_VP8_Encoder to muxer_WebM, exiting...";
        return 2;
    }

    if( !gst_element_link( muxer_WebM, sink_TCPServer ) ) {
        std::cout << "Error linking creating muxer_WebM to sink_TCPServer, exiting...";
        return 2;
    }


    /// Set State of the GStreamer Pipeline to Playing
    GstStateChangeReturn ret = gst_element_set_state( pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING );

    if( ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE ) {
        std::cout << "Error setting GStreamer-Pipeline to playing.";
        return 2;
    }

    Create_PipelineGraph( pipeline );


    /// Start the Heartbeat, that continously creates new Images
    heartbeat->expires_from_now( boost::posix_time::milliseconds( heartbeat_Intervall ) );
    heartbeat->async_wait( Push_new_Image );

    /// ####################
    /// Shutdown the Sandbox
    /// ####################
    std::cout << "Wait some Seconds before joining all Threads and shutdown the Sandbox..." << std::endl;
    boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::seconds( 4 ) );

    std::cout << "Shutdown Sandbox..." << std::endl;
    g_main_loop_quit( glib_MainLoop );
    io_service->stop();

    while( !io_service->stopped() ) {
        boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::seconds( 1 ) );
    }

    work.reset();
    threadgroup->join_all();

    g_main_loop_unref( glib_MainLoop );

    threadgroup.reset();
    work.reset();
    io_service.reset();

    std::cout << "Sandbox stopped" << std::endl;
}

target_link_libraries( Sandbox ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${GSTREAMER_0_10_LIBRARIES} ${GSTREAMER_0_10_APP_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

set_target_properties( Sandbox PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX )
```

I'm starting the Sandbox-Program as follows:

```
LC_ALL="C" GST_DEBUG=3 GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR=/tmp/ ./Sandbox
```

Then a Graph of the current Pipeline should be created in /tmp/. This .dot File can be converted into e.g. a svg-Graphic with:

```
dot -Tsvg -oPipelineGraph.svg PipelineGraph.dot
```

Directly after the Error occurs. Here is the short Message, optained via GST_DEBUG=3:

```
...
0:00:00.141888460 28057      0x2245d90 INFO                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2562:gst_base_src_loop:<Source_OpenCV> pausing after gst_pad_push() = not-negotiated
0:00:00.141924274 28057      0x2245d90 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2625:gst_base_src_loop:<Source_OpenCV> error: Internal data flow error.
0:00:00.141937917 28057      0x2245d90 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2625:gst_base_src_loop:<Source_OpenCV> error: streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
0:00:00.141965714 28057      0x2245d90 INFO        GST_ERROR_SYSTEM gstelement.c:1964:gst_element_message_full:<Source_OpenCV> posting message: Internal data flow error.
0:00:00.141998959 28057      0x2245d90 INFO        GST_ERROR_SYSTEM gstelement.c:1987:gst_element_message_full:<Source_OpenCV> posted error message: Internal data flow error.
0:00:00.142018539 28057      0x2245d90 ERROR                 vp8enc gstvp8enc.c:1028:gst_vp8_enc_finish:<Converter_VP8_Encoder> encode returned 1 error
0:00:00.142053733 28057      0x2245d90 INFO             matroskamux matroska-mux.c:2226:gst_matroska_mux_start:<ebmlwrite0> DocType: webm, Version: 2
0:00:00.142082043 28057      0x2245d90 INFO               ebmlwrite ebml-write.c:218:gst_ebml_writer_send_new_segment_event: seeking to 0
0:00:00.142093688 28057      0x2245d90 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:606:gst_event_new_new_segment_full: creating newsegment update 0, rate 1.000000, format bytes, start 0, stop -1, position 0
...
```

With GST_DEBUG=4 it looks like:

```
...
0:00:02.464122744 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG               GST_CAPS gstpad.c:2925:gst_pad_get_allowed_caps:<Converter_VP8_Encoder:src> allowed caps video/x-vp8, width=(int)[ 16, 4096 ], height=(int)[ 16, 4096 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ]
0:00:02.464152446 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG               GST_CAPS gstpad.c:2263:gst_pad_get_caps_unlocked:<Converter_VP8_Encoder:sink> pad getcaps returned video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)[ 16, 4096 ], height=(int)[ 16, 4096 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], format=(fourcc)I420
0:00:02.464174847 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG               GST_PADS gstpad.c:2577:gst_pad_acceptcaps_default:<Converter_VP8_Encoder:sink> allowed caps video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)[ 16, 4096 ], height=(int)[ 16, 4096 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], format=(fourcc)I420
0:00:02.464198411 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG               GST_PADS gstpad.c:2629:gst_pad_accept_caps:<Converter_VP8_Encoder:sink> acceptfunc returned 1
0:00:02.464210382 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG          basetransform gstbasetransform.c:1082:gst_base_transform_find_transform:<Converter_FFMpegColorSpace> Input caps were video/x-raw-rgb, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)0/1, and got final caps video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)0/1, format=(fourcc)I420
0:00:02.464236195 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG          basetransform gstbasetransform.c:810:gst_base_transform_configure_caps:<Converter_FFMpegColorSpace> in caps:  video/x-raw-rgb, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)0/1
0:00:02.464252757 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG          basetransform gstbasetransform.c:811:gst_base_transform_configure_caps:<Converter_FFMpegColorSpace> out caps: video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)0/1, format=(fourcc)I420
0:00:02.464271709 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG          basetransform gstbasetransform.c:819:gst_base_transform_configure_caps:<Converter_FFMpegColorSpace> have_same_caps: 0
0:00:02.464282177 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG          basetransform gstbasetransform.c:2921:gst_base_transform_set_in_place:<Converter_FFMpegColorSpace> setting in_place FALSE
0:00:02.464292338 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG          basetransform gstbasetransform.c:2860:gst_base_transform_set_passthrough:<Converter_FFMpegColorSpace> set passthrough 0
0:00:02.464302369 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG          basetransform gstbasetransform.c:834:gst_base_transform_configure_caps:<Converter_FFMpegColorSpace> Calling set_caps method to setup caps
0:00:02.464318339 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG       ffmpegcolorspace gstffmpegcolorspace.c:320:gst_ffmpegcsp_set_caps:<Converter_FFMpegColorSpace> could not configure context for input format
0:00:02.464329667 28483      0x24b8590 WARN           basetransform gstbasetransform.c:1311:gst_base_transform_setcaps:<Converter_FFMpegColorSpace> FAILED to configure caps <Converter_FFMpegColorSpace:src> to accept video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)0/1, format=(fourcc)I420
0:00:02.464352143 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG               GST_CAPS gstpad.c:2773:gst_pad_set_caps:<Converter_FFMpegColorSpace:sink> caps video/x-raw-rgb, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)0/1 could not be set
0:00:02.464504648 28483      0x24b8590 INFO                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2562:gst_base_src_loop:<Source_OpenCV> pausing after gst_pad_push() = not-negotiated
0:00:02.464517617 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG                basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2588:gst_base_src_loop:<Source_OpenCV> pausing task, reason not-negotiated
0:00:02.464531137 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG               GST_PADS gstpad.c:5646:gst_pad_pause_task:<Source_OpenCV:src> pause task
0:00:02.464543705 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG                   task gsttask.c:698:gst_task_set_state:<Source_OpenCV:src> Changing task 0x24c9000 to state 2
0:00:02.464585246 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG              GST_EVENT gstevent.c:269:gst_event_new: creating new event 0x24b8940 eos 86
0:00:02.464618078 28483      0x24b8590 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2625:gst_base_src_loop:<Source_OpenCV> error: Internal data flow error.
0:00:02.464631538 28483      0x24b8590 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2625:gst_base_src_loop:<Source_OpenCV> error: streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
0:00:02.464645609 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG            GST_MESSAGE gstelement.c:1933:gst_element_message_full:<Source_OpenCV> start
0:00:02.464672918 28483      0x24b8590 INFO        GST_ERROR_SYSTEM gstelement.c:1964:gst_element_message_full:<Source_OpenCV> posting message: Internal data flow error.
0:00:02.464697059 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG                GST_BUS gstbus.c:308:gst_bus_post:<bus0> [msg 0x2325680] posting on bus, type error, GstMessageError, gerror=(GError)NULL, debug=(string)"gstbasesrc.c\(2625\):\ gst_base_src_loop\ \(\):\ /GstPipeline:OpenCV_to_TCPServer/GstAppSrc:Source_OpenCV:\012streaming\ task\ paused\,\ reason\ not-negotiated\ \(-4\)"; from source <Source_OpenCV>
0:00:02.464727109 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG                    bin gstbin.c:3164:gst_bin_handle_message_func:<OpenCV_to_TCPServer> [msg 0x2325680] handling child Source_OpenCV message of type error
0:00:02.464739521 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG                    bin gstbin.c:3171:gst_bin_handle_message_func:<OpenCV_to_TCPServer> got ERROR message, unlocking state change
0:00:02.464750463 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG                    bin gstbin.c:3441:gst_bin_handle_message_func:<OpenCV_to_TCPServer> posting message upward
0:00:02.464770307 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG                GST_BUS gstbus.c:308:gst_bus_post:<bus1> [msg 0x2325680] posting on bus, type error, GstMessageError, gerror=(GError)NULL, debug=(string)"gstbasesrc.c\(2625\):\ gst_base_src_loop\ \(\):\ /GstPipeline:OpenCV_to_TCPServer/GstAppSrc:Source_OpenCV:\012streaming\ task\ paused\,\ reason\ not-negotiated\ \(-4\)"; from source <Source_OpenCV>
0:00:02.464792364 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG                GST_BUS gstbus.c:338:gst_bus_post:<bus1> [msg 0x2325680] pushing on async queue
0:00:02.464804471 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG                GST_BUS gstbus.c:343:gst_bus_post:<bus1> [msg 0x2325680] pushed on async queue
0:00:02.464824022 28483      0x24b8590 DEBUG                GST_BUS gstbus.c:334:gst_bus_post:<bus0> [msg 0x2325680] dropped
0:00:02.464835553 28483      0x24b8590 INFO        GST_ERROR_SYSTEM gstelement.c:1987:gst_element_message_full:<Source_OpenCV> posted error message: Internal data flow error.
...
```

GST_DEBUG=5 would exceed the limit of this Post. :)

I'm reading the Log in that Way that there exists a problem with transfering the image from the Source_OpenCV to the Converter_FFMpegColorSpace Element? But why can't converter_FFMpegColorSpace handle the data? I thought i provided x-raw-rgb to Converter_FFMpegColorSpace, so it can convert it to x-raw-yuv for Converter_VP8_Encoder. Do i have specified the pushed image in a wrong Way?

If i'm missing some Information, i'm glad to get Hint, so i can add them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you set video/x-raw-rgb,width=640,height=480,framerate=0/1 as caps. That's not complete, you also need to provide the red, green and blue masks, the endianness and the alpha mask if this is ARGB. Check e.g. the ffmpegcolorspace sink template caps as an example and chose the correct format from that.

Also consider using GStreamer 1.x instead of the old and unmaintained 0.10 version. There it's also easier to specify the caps as it just has to be video/x-raw,format=ARGB,width=640,height=480,framerate=0/1 for this case (assuming it's ARGB and not BGRA or BGRx or whatever).

IIRC opencv uses RGB or RGBA.

Comment: I tried it with GStreamer 1.x and i was able to get it working. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please update your question with your working version or post it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

opencv output format is rgb, but vp8enc sink caps is follows :

```
 SINK template: 'sink'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      video/x-raw-yuv
                 format: I420
                  width: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
                 height: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
              framerate: [ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ]
```

You need to convert rgb -> yuv, I made convert yuv2rgb and back between opencv and gstreamer, If you need I can share my code with you.

Comment: The ffmpegcolorspace element from gst-plugins-base converts between video formats n 0.10. (In 1.0 the element is called videoconvert)